# Extracting unique values based multiple criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I created an array function formula to extract a list of profit centers based on multiple criteria. I have 2 categories

1. Active
2. Inactive

I want to capture all profit centers that are categorized as Active.

`+index($F:$F,Match(0,IF($A$1=$C:$C,COUNTIF($B2:B3,$F:$F),""),0))`

My formula is broken down like this..

```
Column A1 = "active"
Column C = categorization of active or inactive
Column B2 = where I'd like the list to begin
Column F = List of profit centers
```

Essentially the reason I need the formula to capture the entire list of active profit center on a different sheet is due to needing to provide additional back up documentation. Once I can populate the list of profit centers I can easily use other formulas to grab financial data by looking up that profit center.

Below is a sample of my dataset where I have all of my profit centers.

| Contract Status | Contract Cat | Profit Center |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ACTIVE | MAO | 3SCC |
| ACTIVE | S-3 | 3DFC |
| INACTIVE | Inact | 3DJH |
| ACTIVE | Minor | 3SBG |

The formula how I have it now works perfect. The only issue is it takes WAY TO LONG to carucate due to the array. This makes the formula not realistic for the work place.

I was hoping someone could help me create a better formula or things I can do to make it not take so long to calculate. I have over 600 profit centers within those 4 type of categories. TIA

Comment: Can you include some sample data? Copy sample data from Excel, go to https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables, paste the data from Excel. Then, click "Generate" and edit the generated Markdown into your question.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I updated the question and added sample data with more information / background. Any help would be greatly appreciated. let me know if what I'm saying now makes sense.

Comment: Could you include a similar table with the data you expect to get? Also, why can't you use AutoFilter for this (**Data** -> **Sort & Filter** -> **Filter**)? And would you be amenable to a VBA solution, either from a different workbook / file or from this one?

Comment: @ZevSpitz I cant use auto filter because the list of active profit centers needs to be in a separate tab with back up documentation showing the changes in sales / profit values from quarter to quarter. Its essentially a list of active profit centers with sales / profit deltas. I could go on my main data tab filter on active and copy / paste those into this new sheet so everything calculates but I'm trying to make it automatic.

Comment: @ZevSpitz honestly it would even be nice if I could make this one sheet be on manual calc that way I can work on other tabs and not have it work super slow. Is there a way to deactivate this one sheet to have it set on manual calc?

Comment: There is [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/disable-calculations-of-a-specified-sheet.545734/post-2694666) -- go into the VBA editor, to the Immediate pane, and set the `EnableCalculation` property on the worksheet to `False`. But would a VBA solution that reads the entire worksheet, filters out certain records, and pastes the filtered data into a new worksheet, be what you're looking for?

Comment: If you have Office 365 Excel you can simply use the `FILTER` function.